# XML to HTML text area from server file system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to display an XML document in a text area on a web page?
I need to get the `importXML` functioning, but I'm not quite sure how to start. I will be using Chrome.

```
var xmlStr = importXML("contacts.xml")
var elm = document.getElementById("xml");
elm.value = xmlStr;
```

Comment: Maybe textarea can only display text so you might want to convert your xml into a string with `String()` ???

Comment: You'll need to show us your `importXML` function before we can have any idea about why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sebastien — No, it will be automatically stringified when assigned to `elm.value`.

Comment: is `importXML` an asynchronous?

Comment: Define "does not work". What does it do? Does it give you unexpected data in the textarea? Does it throw any errors in your JS log? Do you get the expected network traffic? etc.

Comment: I don't have anything for the importXML.  I know it has to be done, but I am not quite sure on how to process it.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is Ajax. There are many tutorials out there.

Comment: @Quentin Does this have to be done in Ajax, or is that just the simplest?

Comment: Getting data from the server with JavaScript is what Ajax *means*.

Comment: @Quentin Asynchronous Javascript and XML, I'm aware.  I'm not familiar with it in any means in order to do what I need to do.  If you can point me in a proper direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax

Comment: @Quentin Wow, thanks!  I never would have thought to use Google.  Who knew that I could get all these results from something simple.  I hope you get a raise.

Answer (score 2):

Since you included jQuery tag I will dare to use it. This could get you started.

```
var textarea = $("#xml"); // this is your textarea element

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url to your xml",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
        textarea.text(xmlText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter.  What about the textarea element, is that replacing the current one I had or changing the value?

Comment: Basically, does the var textarea auto created with Jquery or do I need to link it to `<textarea id="xmldata"</textarea>` Thanks.

Comment: You link your created textarea element using the id `var textarea = $("#xml");`, in the success callback you only re-use this reference to update the text within the textarea. It doesn't replace the whole textarea DOM element.